# Matrix multiplication algorithm

Tags: c++, matrix

I have mat2, mat3 and mat4 classes which denote 2x2, 3x3 and 4x4 matrices, respectively. I am trying to implement a multiplication algorithm by overloading the `*=` operator. Taking mat4 as an example, here is the declaration:

```
mat4& operator*=(const mat4 &m);
```

The multiplication algorithm will return a reference to the calling object. What that means is it will return a reference to `this`. The implementation of the multiplication algorithm is defined thus:

```
mat4& mat4::operator *=(const mat4& m)
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < row(); i++)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < col(); j++)
        {
            for (uint k = 0; k < m.col(); k++)
            {
                data[i][j] += (data[i][k] * m.data[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Where `uint` is a typedef of `unsigned int`. Because the operator overload is a class function, there's no need to have a lhs matrix but instead provide a rhs matrix which I call `m`. The functions `row()` and `col()` in this case will always return 4 since it is a mat4x4; these functions are part of the mat4 class. The attribute `data` is a 2-dimensional array of floats with a fixed size. The problem is that this algorithm doesn't produce the correct result. For example:

```
mat4 m1(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 30.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 30.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

mat4 m2(23.0, 21.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        10.0, 9.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        3.0, 2.0, 9.0, 9.0);

auto result = m1 * m2;

cout << result << endl;
```

Just so you know, I overloaded the `<<` operator as well to make `cout`s with the matrices possible and easy. Just so you are also aware, my matrices are column-major because I intend to use them with OpenGL. Thus something like `m1.data[3][2]` means 4th column, 3rd row. The result is hardly what it is supposed to be:

```
mat4 = 
[ 
    24   5040   5040    54
    10   2110   2110    40
    1    212    213     31
    0    0      0       1
]
```

My issue is that the multiplication algorithm doesn't work and produces the correct result. How do I go about correcting the algorithm so that it produces the correct result as a result of matrix multiplication?

I currently overload the `*` operator like so:

```
mat4 mat4::operator *(const mat4& m) const
{
    mat4 result = *this;
    result *= m;
    return result;
}
```

This utilises the `*=` operator overload. Unfortunately the `*` operator overload won't work either.

Comment: You're getting wrong results because you're setting new values _while you still use them to calculate others_. You need to create a temp object and store the values there.

Comment: In this case it might be easier to do the work in `operator *` and use that to implement `operator *=`. The computation cost is going to dominate anyway.

Comment: @AlanStokes May you show me how I can go about this? I managed to sort out the issue with the `*=` but now the `*` operator overload is screwed. Let me show you how I implement it currently in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems is that you mess the data (You read from and write into the same variable during the calculations) in the `data` field of `(*this)` so you have wrong data.

You need to use a temp matrix and then copy its data after the calculations:

```
mat2& operator*=(const mat2 &m)
{
    // I set all the elements of the temp_data to 0. It is very important
    array<array<int, 2>,2> temp_data = {{{0,0},{0,0}}};
    for (uint i = 0; i < row(); i++)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < col(); j++)
        {
            for (uint k = 0; k < m.col(); k++)
            {
                temp_data[i][j] += (data[i][k] * m.data[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    this->data = temp_data;
    return *this;
}
```

Example of use:

```
int main()
{
    array<array<int, 2>,2> data1 = {{{1,0},{0,1}}};
    array<array<int, 2>,2> data2 = {{{1,2},{3,4}}};
    mat2 m1;
    m1.data = data1;
    mat2 m2;
    m2.data = data2;
    m1 *= m2;
    for (auto el: m1.data) {
        for (auto ele : el) {
            cout << ele << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
1 2                                                 
3 4
```

Comment: Thank you! I've solved my issue thanks to your insight as well as others.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are writing over the same matrix as you are reading from. This means you are using some of the values from the resultant matrix in the calculation instead of the values in the original matrix.

To fix this create a temporary 2 dimensional array to which you can write to:

```
mat4& mat4::operator *=(const mat4& m)
{
    float buffer[4][4]; // Temporary matrix
    for (uint i = 0; i < row(); i++)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < col(); j++)
        {
            // You might want to set the values in the buffer to 0 just in case:
            buffer[i][j] = 0.0f;
            for (uint k = 0; k < m.col(); k++)
            {
                buffer[i][j] += data[i][k] * m.data[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Now that all the values of the new matrix have been calculated you can write to data
    for (uint i = 0; i < row(); i++)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < col(); j++)
        {
           data[i][j] = buffer[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You didn't set the elements of the temp matrix to 0, so you might have wrong results

Comment: read line 8, its more efficient to set them to 0 just before you calculate its value than to create a for loop at the start of the program which is technically what you are doing with the std::array s

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I guess that using `memset` is even more efficient;)